# laravel Pagination empty data when there are not enough records

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-livewire

I am implementing a datatable and I have an error when I select the last page and show 50 records, which is the maximum, this query returns nothing. Isn't it supposed to show the amount of data that exists? There is no conditional in the pagination to put an equal or less?, how can I solve it?

```
 public function render()
    {
          $cli = Client::where('name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')
                                ->orwhere('last_name','like','%'.$this->search.'%')
                                ->orderBy($this->sort, $this->direction)
                                ->paginate($this->cant);
   
        return view('clients.index', compact('cli'))->extends('layouts.template')->section('content');
 
    }
```

Comment: If you update the number of items per page, you should also reset the page count to 1 to avoid this sort of issue. You'll have a hard time figuring out which page should be the new page number if you change the number of items.